# How is the default subnet mask value calculated?

Tags: networking, subnet

The default subnet masks are three subnet masks that correspond to the standard Class **A**, **B**, and **C** address assignments.

```
Class   Binary                                Dotted-Decimal    Network Prefix
A       11111111 00000000 00000000 00000000   255.0.0.0         /8
B       11111111 11111111 00000000 00000000   255.255.0.0       /16
C       11111111 11111111 11111111 00000000   255.255.255.0     /24
```

For class C, it is `255.255.255.0`. How is this base value determined and why is it `255.255.255.0`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you have a class C IP address with a subnet mask of 255.255.0.0?](https://superuser.com/questions/201837/can-you-have-a-class-c-ip-address-with-a-subnet-mask-of-255-255-0-0)

Comment: @harrymc : A subnet mask is defined as 32-bit combination used to describe which portion of an address refers to the subnet and which part refers to the host. If i put my question other way, it would be asking as to why the network portion is represented by 1's and host by 0's?

Comment: The entire first 3 octets are the network portion while the last octet is the host, that's why it's all 1s and equals 255.255.255.0. Remember, this is the subnet and not the actual address like 192.168.1.1